# Mac OS X Mojave Typing Lag

Tags: mac, language

When typing Hebrew letters, the output is delayed and quite laggy. This is not happening in English, as can be seen in the following video (when nothing is being outputted - I actually press the `ש` button, it only gets displayed when I release it):
[image]

It happens with every application, not just with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Character Picker by typing this command on terminal:

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Comment: There's no character picker in Hebrew, I don't see how it could play a role in this problem.